# DownloadTexture not working in iOS devices

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

Am trying to download a texture from a UnityWebRequest and trying to set to a image (or any gameobject like Cube/Sphere etc), but I keep getting the error. Tried www method as well, but that does not work either.

*Am checking on a iPhone 6 with iOS 10.3*

**InvalidOperationException: Texture has not yet finished downloading**
It works fine in Unity Play mode, but does not work when I test it in the device.

```
 UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
 DownloadHandlerTexture textD = new DownloadHandlerTexture ();
 www.downloadHandler = textD;
 yield return www.Send();
 while (!www.isDone) {
     yield return ww; 
 }
 if (www.isError) {
     Debug.Log ("ImageRenderScript..Error in  web service::" + www.error);
 } else {
     var tex = new Texture2D (size, size);
     tex.LoadImage (textD.data);
     Rect rec = new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height);
     imageObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Sprite.Create(tex,rec,new Vector2(0.5f,0.5f),100);
```

Can someone pls help? I have been trying to look for solutions, but could not find any.

Comment: What's your Unity version? Also, does this code work in the Editor? I suggest you put the url you are making the request to in your question. It could be that too.

Comment: @Programmer - I use Unity 5.5.2. XCode 8.2. Am checking on a iPhone 6 with iOS 10.3. Yes, the code works in the editor, but not in the device build only. I tried with different image urls - from S3, google maps static map and few others.

Comment: Remove `while (!www.isDone) {`. You don't need that since you are already yielding with `yield return www.Send()`. Let me know what happens.

Comment: @Programmer - Thanks for the suggestion. It does not help much. It gives me same issue only - 'InvalidOperationException: Texture has not yet finished downloading'.

Comment: Ok. Add `yield return null` after the `yield return www.Send()`. That will make it wait one frame. Let me know if it is not working. I might test this on iphone device to see what's going on.

Comment: @Programmer - I tried  www.downloadHandler = textD;
 yield return www.Send();
yield return null;           but it did not work either.

Comment: I remember seeing this as a bug. Please update to Unity 5.6 or use Unity's `WWW` API.

Comment: @Programmer - I will try updating to Unity 5.6 and see. I already tried WWW API. But it gives me error "Unsupported url. " when trying on device. Again works fine in Unity Player. 

I read in some posts that WWW does not work well in iOS and to try UnityWebRequest instead. Hence I tried this and ran into issue in this as well.

Comment: Updating seems to be the only reasonable option now.

Comment: @Programmer - Thank you. Updating to Unity 5.6 did the trick. I was doing 'Check for updates' and it always got back as up to date. so I did not realize that there was an updated version available.

Comment: Great. I remember that bug. Glad that fixed it.